# Tracking Google Ads and Facebook Ads in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Am slightly confused over how to use Ads (Facebook / Google) together with Google Analytics. Can someone please help me out?

My overall objective: To pass information from Facebook Ads and Google Ads into Google Analytics.

***Google Ads***

**Background:** ValueTrack Parameters can be used to pass information into Google Analytics. For example, if I want to track the Landing Page and Creative ID, I would this: `{lpurl}?creative={creative}`
(Source: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6305529)

**Question 1:** Where would the Landing Page and Creative ID show up in Google Analytics? Would they appear as Custom Dimensions or in their respective Secondary Dimensions here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWFpu.png?

**Question 2:** I understand that you can override dimensions in Google Analytics. (Source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033981?hl=en&ref_topic=1308612). Am I restricted to overriding dimensions listed in the GA Campaign URL Builder (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) ? In other words - Campaign Source, Campaign Medium, Campaign Name, Campaign Term and Campaign Content?

**Question 3:** If the answer to Question 2 is no, then where can I find a full list of dimensions I can override? This will also help me avoid creating custom parameters that coincide with what Google Analytics uses by default. I found this list of parameters (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/). But I am not sure how to interpret this.

Let’s use the Secondary Dimension Creative ID as an example. In this link (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#ga:adwordsCreativeID), I am not told what parameter I should be using if I wish to pass information into it.

**Question 4:** If I want to pass information into a particular Secondary Dimension field, where can I check what form it has to be in? For example, if I want to pass information into the Secondary Dimension Google Ads Creative ID (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo6Oz.png), what do I have to add to URL to be able to do this? Based on the information above, it seems like I have to use the parameter `creative` eg. `www.mywebsite.com/creative={creative}`. How exactly do I check what parameter to use?

***Facebook Ads***

**Background:** Facebook offers a list of dynamic URL parameters that we can use to push additional information into Google Analytics (https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1016122818401732).

**Question 5:** Where would these parameters like `ad_id={{ad.id}}` show up in Google Analytics? Would they appear as a Custom Dimension or in the Google Ads Creative ID dimension here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo6Oz.png?

**Question 6:** Can I confirm that Facebook Ads only offers very few URL parameters for us to track with (source: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1016122818401732)? This is so much lesser than what is offered by Google Ads.

```
ad_id={{ad.id}}
adset_id={{adset.id}}
campaign_id={{campaign.id}}
ad_name={{ad.name}}
adset_name={{adset.name}}
campaign_name={{campaign.name}}
placement={{placement}}
site_source_name={{site_source_name}}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can link **Google Ads** at the Property Analytics level and the cost data and ad information will be automatically imported. You will see them in the related report **Acquisition -> Google Ads**.

**Facebook Ads** data are not automatically imported (Facebook is not owned by Google, at least not yet :D) so you need to import it independently through the function **Data import** at Property level in Google Analytics, choosing *Cost Data*, so you can import cost data for non-Google marketing campaigns (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6015070?hl=en).